# Difference of C# TcpListener & Java ServerSocket

Tags: c#, java, android

I'm working on file transfer program between PC & Android Device. but I found a problem in PC server part.

First, my android app request connection to PC like below.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        InetAddress lServerAddress = InetAddress.getByAddress(
            new byte[] { (byte)192, (byte)168, (byte)0, (byte)196 });
        Socket lClient = new Socket();
        lClient.bind(null);
        lClient.connect(new InetSocketAddress(lServerAddress, 12303), 20000);
        OutputStream lOutput = lClient.getOutputStream();
        lOutput.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(123456).array());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(AppManager.msLogTag, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This codes are executed in worker thread.

And then server codes in Java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ServerSocket lServer = new ServerSocket(12303);
        Socket lClient = lServer.accept();
        System.out.println("Accepted.");
        InputStream lReadStream = lClient.getInputStream();
        byte[] lBuffer = new byte[4];
        lReadStream.read(lBuffer, 0, lBuffer.length);
        ByteBuffer lBytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(lBuffer);
        System.out.println(lBytes.getInt());
        lReadStream.close();
        lClient.close();
        lServer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It works perfectly.

However in C#, `TcpListener` do not accept client forever. Here is source.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IPAddress lServerIp = null;
    foreach (IPAddress lIp in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()))
    {
        if (lIp.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            lServerIp = lIp;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (lServerIp != null)
    {
        TcpListener lServer = new TcpListener(lServerIp, 12303);
        Console.WriteLine(lServerIp.ToString());
        lServer.Start();
        using (Socket lClient = lServer.AcceptSocket())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(((IPEndPoint)lClient.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());
            using (Stream lStream = new NetworkStream(lClient))
            {
                byte[] lBuffer = new byte[4];
                lStream.Read(lBuffer, 0, lBuffer.Length);
                int lHead = BitConverter.ToInt32(lBuffer, 0);
                Console.WriteLine(lHead.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Environments are same, port forwarded and registered firewall exception. So I think, Java's `ServerSocket` and C#'s `TcpListener` are working differently. However, TCProtocol has world standard, BTW how can they working differently? I cannot understand this situation.

Finally, how can I fix C# server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both languages should work the same, and I can't see any obvious bugs in your code. However it's not clear what IP address your using for all your examples:

a) Your java example doesn't specify an IP address to bind to (I assume by default it will bind to 0.0.0.0 i.e all local IP addresses, but you can check using netstat).

b) The C# code will just bind to the first IP address it finds. This could be something like 127.0.0.1.

To make sure, just change both code fragments to explicitly bind to the expected IP address (192.168.0.196) and try again.

Comment: Oh, I got it. The IP was the problem. Hardcode to `IPAddress lServerIp = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.196");`, it works. BTW how can I find this address in addresses list automately like in Java? It has 6 elements but finding address is not first one.

Comment: I haven't tested (and the docs are not clear), but I suspect Java will connect to "0.0.0.0" by default. This means "any address" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0). You could try doing something similar in C# - just use IPAddress.Any (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.ipaddress.any)

Comment: Also please upvote/accept the answer if this has solved your problem.